# Como resolver problemas de acentuação ao usar a função setlocale?

Tags: c, acentuação

Estou tentando definir a linguagem do programa para português, usando o `setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese")`, porém, grande parte do programa foi feito em Ubuntu. Quando o outro programador me enviou os arquivos e quando vou compilar, usando o mingw32-make para usar o makefile, tenho problemas com a acentuação, mas quando compilo usando Ubuntu não tenho esse problema.

Sendo a biblioteca `locale.h` padrão da linguagem C, esse `setlocale` deveria funcionar tanto em Windows quanto em Ubuntu. Alguém tem ideia de qual é o problema?

Answer (score 4):

Isso tem a ver com a codificação do arquivo e a codificação de saída do seu programa.

O problema não vai simplesmente ir embora sozinho - você precisa entender Unicode. Sugiro que leia [este artigo - a peça mais clássica sobre unicode que já vi, em circulação desde 2003](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)).

Isso acontece por que o "locale" do programa depende de uma codificação interna da acentuação (qual o código do caractére "ç"?  No terminal do Ubuntu vai ser um, no terminal (cmd) do Windows vai ser outro, e numa janela gráfica no mesmo Windows vai ser um terceiro valor)  - entender Unicode é saber que você precisa:

1. Normalizar todos os seus dados de entrada, venham da internet, do banco de dados, de entrada do usuário, de sensores externos, etc... para uma única codificação itnerna que seja usada pelas suas bibliotecas que trabalham com texto (UTF-16 e UTF32 costumam ser usadas - mas se não me engano o sistema gobject usa utf-8 mesmo)
2. Executar todo o seu processamento: comparações, interpolação, classificação, etc...com essa codificação
3. Codificar de volta o texto para o encoding da mídia alvo quando for salvar - e nada obriga que tenha que ser a mesma codificação para cada saída - você pode dar saída para o terminal do Windows com uma codificação, para o banco de dados com outra, e ainda gerar uma saída em HTML com outra. (Mas o mais recomendado é configurar tudo o que se comunica com seu programa para usar utf-8  - facilita muito as coisas)

Answer (score 3):

Na função `setLocale` coloque como segundo parâmetro a string `""` (aspas duplas), talvez isso resolva pois dessa forma a localização é configurada de acordo com a localidade do SO.

exemplo:

```
setLocale(LC_ALL,"");
```