# Formatar data no PHP Inglês e Espanhol?

Tags: php

Tenho esse código `PHP` para formatar as data vindas de um `SQL`:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

preciso fazer também para **Inglês** e **Espanhol**, como eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Já leu a documentação dessas duas funções? O que entendeu e o que não entendeu?

Comment: Pode criar uma função que pede como argumento o idioma e retorna a data no formato desejado.

Comment: Leitura disponível: http://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=857:mostrar-fecha-en-espanol-php-setlocale-strftime-formato-datedefault-timezone-set-ejemplos-cu00831b&catid=70&Itemid=193

Comment: SOEn - exemplo espanhol: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635303/get-day-from-string-in-spanish-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só seguir a mesma linha, colocando os parâmetros conforme a região, exemplo:

***Espanhol:***

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES', 'es_ES.utf-8', 'es_ES.utf-8', 'esp');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Mendoza');
echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y");
```

***Brasil***

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
echo strftime("%A %d de %B de %Y");
```

***EUA***

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'us', 'us.utf-8', 'us.utf-8');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo strftime("%A %d de %B of %Y");
```

***Algumas respostas que podem contribuir com informações adicionais:***

- [Usar o setlocale apenas para a date](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210572/usar-o-setlocale-apenas-para-a-date)
- [Como resolver problemas de acentuação ao usar a função setlocale?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112263/como-resolver-problemas-de-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-usar-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-setlocale)
- [Data em português (pt-br)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183518/data-em-portugu%C3%AAs-pt-br)
- [Como fazer a função date() formatar uma data em português?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%C3%AAs)
- [Converter data MySQL (YYYY/mm/dd h:m:s) para dd/mm/aaaa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51692/converter-data-mysql-yyyy-mm-dd-hms-para-dd-mm-aaaa/51693)

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Timezones America](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.america.php)
- [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)
- [PHP date_default_timezone_set() Eastern Standard Time (EST) - SO<sup>En</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559103/php-date-default-timezone-set-eastern-standard-time-est)
- [COMO DEFINIR DATETIMEZONE EM PHP?](http://pequenasduvidas.com/como-definir-datetimezone-em-php/)
- [PHP setlocale() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_setlocale.asp)
- [FECHAS EN ESPAÑOL CON PHP Y SETLOCALE](https://lachabela.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/fechas-en-espanol-con-php-y-setlocale/)

Comment: eu nao consegui fazer funcionar em espanhol.

`código`setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES', 'es_ES.utf-8', 'es_ES.utf-8', 'esp');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Mendoza');
echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y");

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard os 3 exemplos foram testados e estão corretos, o que é que não deu certo, como você está utilizando?

Comment: Tive que alterar a configuração do meu debian 8. Agora funcionou.